# php include files from directories other than root directory

Tags: php, include

I've got a global template page, `/layout_header.php` as well as some other file stored in `/aFolder/index.php`.

In `/layout_header.php`, I have:

```
<?php
    // Reference to scripts and other files
    echo "<img src='img/lollipop.png'/>";
    echo "<script src='js/move.js'/>";
    echo "<a href='aFolder/movement.php'>Click here!</a>";
?>
```

In `/aFolder/index.php`, I have:

```
<?php
    include "../layout_header.php";
?>
```

Now, `/aFolder/index.php` has no problems calling the `/layout_header.php` file. Unfortunately, because the directory is now `/aFolder`, I face the following problems:

- Unable to view the image, since image is now linked as `/aFolder/img/lollipop.png` (which does not exist)
- Unable to execute script because of reason listed above.
- Invalid URL because of reason listed above.

Many of my scripts and css files are using relative path. In other words, if `index.php` was placed in the root folder, everything works fine.

How should I go about solving the problem of files in subdirectories?

Comment: Always use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'path/to/file' that should solve your issue.

Comment: And for images and script files and css files use http://yourdomain.com/path/to/file.extension

Comment: Do I only have to do that for my layout_header.php file? Or must I also do that for the script files linked?

Comment: Yes, try that and see. include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'path/layout_header.php' Assuming that your website has a folder called path inside which there is the layout_header.php file. And why are you echoing the scripts and images like that? Use normal HTML tags.

Comment: You're right about the HTML tags. I should do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see that in all PHP frameworks (at least professionals) a variable/constant as APPPATH, BASEPATH etc. So you need to define your similar variable/constant in your project and use it as needed.

```
<?php
// a.php: assuming this included everywhere at very first line 
// and located in root directory
// preferable, define a constant instead of variable, cos it 
// may used in functions directly without "global $ROOT";

// for "include"
define('ROOT', __DIR__); // for PHP >= 5.3
define('ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));  // for PHP < 5.3
// for "src, href" etc
define('HTTP', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']); // for local development support i.e foo.com.local

// includes
include ROOT .'/layout_header.php';
include ROOT .'/classes/mailer.php';
include ROOT .'/foo/bar/baz.php';
...

// src,href
printf('<script src="%s/js/move.js" />', HTTP);
printf('<img src="%s/img/lollipop.png" />', HTTP);

print '<a href="'. HTTP .'/aFolder/movement.php">Click here!</a>';
...
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any reason why I should use ROOT instead of HTTP for including php files?

Comment: It's just an alias, you can change it as you like. I used it cos more meaning (root: directory root, http: source address). Also, you can't include files from http.

Answer (score 5):

Always use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'path/to/file' for including php files when it's relative.

And for images and script files and css files use yourdomain.com/path/to/file.extension

Comment: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] prints /home/<user>/public_html/ - is that supposed to be correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct :) So from public_html/yoursite/whateverdirectory/whateverfile.ext

Comment: So if you have a file to be included by traversing back a directory or two, you can use $_SERVER thing and then include. You will have no issues at all :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using complete root instead of relative.

```
define('WEB_ROOT', 'http://yourdomain.com/');  // localhost path etc


echo "<img src=".WEB_ROOT."img/lollipop.png'/>";
echo "<script src=".WEB_ROOT."'js/move.js'/>";
echo "<a href='".WEB_ROOT."aFolder/movement.php'>Click here!</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is many solutions that you can do:

- Go to your config file to change roots of your project.
- Leave the index.php into the folder aFolder/index.php and make a redirection from it to an other file
- Change your htacess file to make a redirection
- Change all path by taking url from the server.

I will took the second one (duplicate the index and put it with /layout_header.php)
Remove the content from aFolder/index.php and add to it a redirection to the other index file:

```
<?php

   header( 'Location: ../index.php' ) ;

?>
```